# RecyclerView Item Count On TextView Only Updates When Re-entering the activity. How To Make It Update In RealTime

Tags: java, android

**I Want The TextView To Be Updated As soon as i remove an item from the recyclerview. the text view only updates when i go to another activity and come back to the activity where the textview was.**

```
 private void getTasks() {
        class GetTasks extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<Task>> {

            @Override
            protected List<Task> doInBackground(Void... voids) {
                List<Task> taskList = DatabaseClient
                        .getInstance(getContext())
                        .getAppDatabase()
                        .taskDao()
                        .getAll();
                return taskList;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(final List<Task> tasks) {
                super.onPostExecute(tasks);
                final TasksAdapter adapter = new TasksAdapter(getContext(), tasks);
             totalGoals =  adapter.getItemCount();


                if (tasks.size() > 0) {
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    introText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                } else {
                    makeMeShake(introText, 20, 10);
                    introText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    getTasks();
                }

                int countTrue = 0 ;

                for(int i = 0; i < tasks.size();i++){
                   // System.out.println("BOOLEANS" + "  :"+i+": "+tasks.get(i).isFinished() + " :" +tasks.size());
                    if(tasks.get(i).isFinished()) {
                        countTrue++;
                    }
                }
               /* if (tasks.size() != 0) {

                    SharedPreferences sp = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("your_prefs", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
                    editor.putInt("gCount", countTrue);
                    editor.apply();

                }*/

                System.out.println("True Items" + countTrue);

                goalProgress.setText(MessageFormat.format("({0} out of {1})",
                        String.valueOf(countTrue), totalGoals));

                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                recyclerView.invalidate();

            }
        }

        GetTasks gt = new GetTasks();
        gt.execute();
    }
```

I think the problem is with (datasetchanged). Please help me out as i have been trying to look for an easy solution by could not find any till now.

Comment: put `notifydatasetchanged` after assigning the adapter to recyclerview

Answer (score 0):

use this one  add

```
      adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

after

```
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

put this

```
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

right after:

```
final TasksAdapter adapter = new TasksAdapter(getContext(), tasks);
```

adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); ---- you can remove

Comment: It didn't solve it. i want it to be changed right after i delete the item from the recyclerview.  Like refresh the activity right now i am at and update the textview.

Comment: totalGoals =  tasks.size();

Comment: No Luck Man still does not refresh :( thank you for the quick responses though!

Answer (score 0):

Simply put **notifydatasetchanged** *after* your data set is changed.

(nonsense putting it after assigning the adapter to the recyclerview)